# Bad shifting result in java

Tags: java, bit-shift

I am trying to perform logical right and left shift (using >>> and <<). Unfortunately I see that all when the shift amount is bigger than 32 it rotate the bits with modulo and than shifts the bit to the right place. It is not really just shifting them. How can I avoid it ? using java 7 in centOS.
**Update:**
after playing with examples I think there is a bug:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0xc0000003;
    int b = a >>> 32;
    int c = 0xc0000003;
    int d = c << 36;
    System.out.println("b=" + b + ", d=" + d);  
}
```

the output is `b=-1073741821, d=48`. Why? How do I shift logic right and left like in c?

Comment: They are called "[Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)". They *shift*, they don't *rotate*. Where did you get the idea that they rotate?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which shows your issue.

Comment: Its more likely you have no idea what are you doing than a more than 20 years old language has a such trivial bug.

Comment: And >>> is not  the right version of <<.

Comment: you are not answering the question... please try before you say it is wrong...what am I doing wrong ? how do I do logic shifts ?

Comment: It's not a bug. C and Java are different languages and just because this works in a certain way in C doesn't mean it works exactly the same in Java. [Java Language Spec 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) explains how bit shift operators work in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In java it is not full shift by the right hand value but this is the answer:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the
>   five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f
>   (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the
>   range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the
>   six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f
>   (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in
>   the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

taken from [The Java® Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). For me, this behavior is not very intuitive ...